# Convert Ruby Code To PHP (Vicurex API)

Tags: php, ruby, api, curl

I'm stuck trying to convert some sample Ruby API code from https://vircurex.com/welcome/api?locale=en to PHP.  Here is the Ruby Code provided:

```
t = Time.now.gmtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S");
trx_id = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{t}-#{rand}")
user_name = "MY_USER_NAME"
secret_word = "123456789"
tok = Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("#{secret_word};#{user_name};#{t};#{trx_id};create_order;sell;10;btc;50;nmc")
Order.call_https("https://vircurex.com", "/api/create_order.json?account=#{user_name}&id=#{trx_id}&token=#{tok}&timestamp=#{t}&ordertype=sell&amount=10&currency1=btc&unitprice=50&currency2=nmc")

def self.call_https(my_url,my_params)
  uri = URI.parse(my_url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, '443')
  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
  response=""
  resp=""
  http.start do |http|
    cmd = my_params
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(cmd)
    response = http.request(req)
    resp = response.body
  end
  return ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(resp)
end
```

Here is what I attempted to come up with so far in PHP, but i know nothing of Ruby, so it is hard to figure out what the original code is doing:

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$t = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
$trx_id = hash("sha256", $t."-".rand()); // i think this is wrong
$user_name = "MY_USER_NAME";
$secret_word = "123456789";
$tok = hash("sha256", $secret_word.";".$user_name.";".$t.";".$trx_id.";create_order;sell;10;btc;50;nmc");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://vircurex.com/api/create_order.json?account=$username&id=$trx_id&token=$tok&timestamp=$t&ordertype=sell&amount=10&currency1=btc&unitprice=50&currency2=nmc");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$resp = curl_exec($ch);
return json_decode($resp);
```

Can someone familiar with both languages please help me out?  Thanks!

I get the following response with my code:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 8003
    [statustxt] => Authentication failed
)
```

So obviously, something is not being translated correctly.  I just need to generate some working PHP code to use with the API listed.  You can create an account to test the code if you like.

Comment: First, you want just `hash`, not `hash_hmac`, where you set `$trx_id` - that one is just a plain old hash, no secret key.

Comment: Have you tried running the Ruby to verify that it works as provided?

Comment: I tried changing to hash() but still same results.  I don't have any way to test the Ruby code, but I know that others use it.

Comment: I think the problem is how i pass the url parameters... can't tell if they should be POST or GET?

Comment: It's a query string, not a request body, and the fact that the Ruby is using `Net::HTTP::Get` makes it an HTTP GET request.

Comment: Ok, I see that now.  So it should be correct as I have it but I'm missing something else just not sure what.

Comment: The ruby code is using hash/sha2. You're using hash_hmac/sha256. Not the same algorithhms at all.

Comment: Other than the fact that compcentral's code is using `hash_hmac` instead of just `hash`, they are the same.  The label "SHA256" is just a shorthand name for the 256-bit version of the SHA2 algorithm.

Comment: I modified the code to show what i currently have (changed hash_hmac to hash).  Any other ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: What does the hexdigest do?  could that be it?

Comment: @compcentral: ruby / `Digest::SHA2.hexdigest('test')` <=> php / `hash('sha256', 'test')`.

Comment: @compcentral: I hate to be asking, but did you actually sign up or such, to be able to log in at all?

Comment: ok i thought that was the case.  Yes, I have an account and have API access enabled.

Comment: What is striking here: ruby does set `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER` while php for unknown reason uses the opposite: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);` Have you tried to explicitly set the latter to true?

Comment: Yes, I tried it both ways at one point, but I'll give it another shot soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on two lines:

First, change this line:

```
$t = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```

to:

```
$t = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", time());
```

And second, fix this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://vircurex.com/api/create_order.json?account=$username&id=$trx_id&token=$tok&timestamp=$t&ordertype=sell&amount=10&currency1=btc&unitprice=50&currency2=nmc");
```

by changing `$username` param into `$user_name`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://vircurex.com/api/create_order.json?account=$user_name&id=$trx_id&token=$tok&timestamp=$t&ordertype=sell&amount=10&currency1=btc&unitprice=50&currency2=nmc");
```

I successfully received a valid response from Vircurex with another API call, as the create_order API is currently disabled as reported on Vircurex site. In any case, I've had no authentication problems.

Comment: Excellent!  I knew I had to be missing something simple.  I can't believe i made the "user_name" mistake.  Code works fine tho now.  Hopefully this will help others.